# very strange situation when i make aspx page inside a folder a default document

Tags: asp.net, iis

i have the structure of the website 
all pages in folders

--- home [directory]

------------------------- home.aspx

------------------------- anything.aspx

------------------------- another.aspx

--- content [directory]

--- users [directory]

.
.
.
etc

so if i make the default document for this site
home/home.aspx

any code inside home.aspx
will not execute
if i redirect to any other page
it does not understand hierarchy of folders
i dont know why
and will go to

home.aspx on the root
which is not exist

so it give an error
not found

because no home.aspx on the root

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try these:

Change the directory name from "Home" to "HomeXYZ"

When redirecting, use "../home.aspx"